# Protect images through .htaccess and PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

I would like to check if users are logged in to access image files.
Images would have this form

```
https://domain.com/folders/imagename.jpg
```

I tried this in the .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}\.jpg
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.jpg$ /protect.php
```

And this in my protect.php file

```
<?php 
if(rcp_is_active()){
   header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
   readfile($imageurl);
}
else{
   readfile("https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=38&txt=Forbidden&w=400&h=400")
}
?>
```

**My question:**

- How should I complete my .htaccess file to pass the filename.jpg to the php file?

Comment: You should not update the question to contain the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your .htaccess [`RewriteRule`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) to pass the matched filename to the PHP script as follows (your RewriteCondition is superfluous):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^((.*)\.jpg)$ /protect.php/$1
```

Then you can access the passes value using `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` or `$_SERVER['PATH_TRANSLATED']` (then Apache tries to map it to the real path according to document root, see [mod_cgi](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_cgi.html) and [RFC 3875](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875) for more information about this). For this to work [`AcceptPathInfo`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo) needs to be enabled in Apache httpd (the default).

or use

```
RewriteRule ^((.*)\.jpg)$ /protect.php?filename=$1
```

and use `$_GET['filename']`. Especially here, beware for directory traversal attacks (e.g., someone uses `/protect.php?filename=../../someother-file.jpg`). I usually apply [`realpath`](https://secure.php.net/manual/de/function.realpath.php) to normalize the path and check that it starts with the folder which contains the files or the document root (`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`).

In both cases also make sure you only deliver allowed files (e.g., what happens if an attacker uses `/protect.php/protect.php`). This might leak sensitive data.

PS: Maybe you also want to make the response non-cacheable or provide a Content-Length.

PSS: Even for the forbidden case you also need to provide a proper Content-Type - or use a redirect (`header('Status: 302');` and `header("Location: https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=38&txt=Forbidden&w=400&h=400");`) so that you don't need to re-request that image again and again.

Comment: Seems great, but I get strange characters

Comment: When I directly access the file ex: url/filename.jpg

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by strange characters.

Comment: Looks like wrong content type, this is the content of a PNG file interpreted as text and not as a PNG (Content-Type: image/png)

Comment: Btw. I forgot to mention: In the filename= case beware of directory traversals...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121398/discussion-between-lucien-dubois-and-mrtux).